# Missing .jar in Java Build Path with backslaches in path

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I am adding new version of TestNG library. So I downloaded new `testng-6.13.1.jar` to the folder `.../tools/testng`, and trying to add reference to it the same way I did for previous version. But new jar is added with backslashes in path and is defined as `(missing)` by the IDE:

[image: new version of testng is missing]

Why is it so?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but you really want 2 version of  testng ?

Comment: I think that problem is about first backslash in your _missing_ path. Path of testng-6.8.jar doesn't start with slash

Comment: @gtosto , no I'm going to use only the latest one, the picture is just for you to compare. Sure I'll remove the old version

Comment: @avix , I'd like to try to remove that first backslash in missing path but the path is added automaticaly by IDE, I just click "Add External JARs..." and select the jar I need in Browse-dialog

Answer (score 1):

If jar is inside somewhere in the workspace use Add JARs... open in this case it will use relative path but if the jar is outside the workspace then use Add External JARs... option which will point to the absolute jar file.

Comment: Great idea, but finally when I tried to add jar as internal one, I couldn't see it in explorer: and refreshing of project tree in Package Explorer solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

As `.jar` file was inside of the project, IDE could not see it untill I did refresh in `Package Explorer`:

[image: Need to do refresh in explorer]

So simply right click on the destination folder of library and select `Refresh` or press F5.

[image]